# price and quantity after taxation

Tags: functions, economics

Given that demand for a good X is equal to $q_D=393-2p$ and market supply is $q_S=p/4-12$. Find equilibrium price and quantity, consumer and producer surplus and draw a diagram illustrating the situation. Given that:

a) $T=20\% \pi$, total profit is taxed

b) $T=200$ tax does not depend on volume and value of goods sold

will it be simply $$393-2p=p/4-12-200$$
? Obviously i need to find $p$.

Obviously i have calculated the equilibrium price and quantity before taxation that is $p=180,q=33$. How to find situation after taxation in those two cases?

Comment: Assuming a competitive market, the supply price for a given quantity should be equal to the marginal cost, and the marginal profit should be zero.

This does not change with either a lump-sum tax or a percentage profit tax, with the same price and quantity giving a zero marginal profit.   

What will change is the producer surplus.

Comment: Could you be more specific? i do not think i get it

Answer (score -2):

$$393 − 2p = \frac p 4 − 12 − 200 - 0.2 \cdot \text{profit} .$$

Comment: I do not understand your answer if possible please clarify what you mean.

Comment: The problem is poorly stated and you did the best you could.

Comment: I know it is poorly stated, but i have no idea what to do with 20% of profits tax still you do not answer my question fully.

Comment: Just subtract it from the right side.

Comment: but what exactly is profit in this case? what is the value of p for the formulae you have shown?

Comment: You can't answer the question because profit is never given. I don't know what your teacher wants. If the profit was phrased as a percent of supply then you could just insert that term.

Comment: What is the purpose then of you answering this question? Why you substract 200 as it is a separate case that should not be included in the latter one.  I would strongly advice you to know the answer for the question before you post an answer that is not a proper answer.